# How do you implement mongoDB's version of identity field in SQL Server?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I always use an int column that is set as identity field as a primary key in a table in MS SQL.  What is the best way to do this on MongoDB?  I know that I can use the oid, but I want to use a number that can easily be read and remembered.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://shiflett.org/blog/2010/jul/auto-increment-with-mongodb) by Chris Shiflett explains how to create auto-incrementing IDs.

It makes use of MongoDB's atomic [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) command to increment and return an integer every time you need a new ID.